# EDI HIPAA X12 Developer tools

Tags: edi, x12, hipaa

What are some develper tools other than Altova Mapforce for mapping HIPAA X12 such as the 837, 835, 277?

Answer (score 3):

A new Web API for EDI claims is the ClearEHR Health Insurance Claims API - this tool doesn't map the data, it replaces the need for any EDI data generation on the developer end as the API handles all of the EDI creation, and parsing the EDI responses. And it is free to use. 
https://837-edi.clearehr.com
JSON encoded responses, and web based (RESTful) make it ideal for web development.

Disclaimer: I am a developer for ClearEHR

Answer (score 1):

This one is free http://x12parser.codeplex.com.
It already has support for some of the HIPAA 4010 and 5010 transactions.
Most anything can be done if you know how to write xslt to customize it to your own xml schema.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.orionhealth.com/products/symphonia/

Answer (score 0):

Chiapas EDI is located at http://chiapas.sourceforge.net, and is used in production at several HMO's and healthcare enterprises.  It supports all 4010 transactions and several 5010 transactions, has a scripting language, and has interfaces towards several databases, flat files and CSV files.  It's open source.

Comment: You appear to be the author of the software you are recommending. It's great if your software does what the OP needs, but here at Stack Overflow we suggest you disclose your affiliation with the software as a part of the answer, otherwise it's often viewed as spam. This applies to your [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802211/is-any-open-source-frameworks-available-for-writing-ansi-837-file/6868708#6868708) too. Thanks! :)