# open source .NET libraries available for writing ANSI 837 files in EDI?

Tags: .net, edi

We have data stored in a database and we need to create an ANSI 837 file from this data. Are there any open source frameworks available to do this in .NET?

Answer (score 7):

- [OopFactory X12 parser](http://x12parser.codeplex.com/) is an open source C# implementation of an X12 parser.
- [EDI notepad](http://liaison.com/products/integrate/edi-notepad) (free version) may also help with this.

Comment: Is there any way of reading/writing X12 EDI 837 files, any open source project in PHP??

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a standard mapper instead of trying to code that beast?  There's a lot of minefields there (ISA/GS enveloping, control numbers, HL segments, segment looping) that EDI translators already have built-in dictionaries to use.

While not open source, there is a company out there who provides programming tools that might help your cause:  http://www.edidev.com/ (more specifically: http://www.edidev.com/edidev_hipaa_support.htm).

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer..  But, here we have to build each segment with business rules.([http://www.edidev.net/edidev-ca/samples/AspNetGen810.htm](http://www.edidev.net/edidev-ca/samples/AspNetGen810.htm)).So, it is defficult. there any thing available in EDIDEv to map database columns & segment value positions.So, that it can be a one time job.Then, i will generate a claim just by sending encounter id.

Comment: You would have to code EVERYTHING using their tool kit.  Based on your requirement, it sounds like you want a mapping utility.  Check out Jitterbit (www.jitterbit.com).  They have an open source integration tool that you can create a map for (Database to EDI).  Their community edition is free.  I'm not the biggest fan of their mapping interface, but if you're able to procure commercial software that will do everything you need to do, check out Delta/ECS from Liaison (www.liaison.com).  Not free, not open source, but wanted to give you options of tools I know that work.

Comment: Actually i am new to EDI world.Once agian i want to tell my requirement. We built a healthcare management system.Using this front office peroson can create appointments for provider.Finally. those appointments will convert in to encounters. So, i have a encounters data in SQL Server Database.Here, we have to provide interface for billing person to look in to encounter data & able to generate claim.Finally, we have to send it to clearing house.So, in single button click we have to generate 837 file. Totally developed in ASP.NET(web).I think our requirement is limited.How do i proceed ??

Comment: Your requirement to code it in ASP.NET is extremely limited.  Your management is asking you to completely reinvent the wheel and develop a solution for one of the more difficult EDI transactions.  Between the segment looping, the enveloping, managing multiple partners, these are all functions that are already available in commercial software.  You have an uphill battle ahead of you, because not only do you have learn EDI, but you have to code everything.  There is a way to embed a Liaison Delta map inside an ASP.NET web page, but I guess that is kind of cheating :)  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

http://chiapas.sourceforge.net

It can be executed from the command line or integrated as a C# component.  It has a 76 page PDF manual which goes over many of the features, check it out.

Comment: You appear to be the author of the software you are recommending. It's great if your software does what the OP needs, but here at Stack Overflow we suggest you disclose your affiliation with the software as a part of the answer, otherwise it's often viewed as spam. This applies to your [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314594/edi-hipaa-x12-developer-tools/6868629#6868629) too. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

not .net, but is open source:
http://bots.sourceforge.net

Comment: Yes,bots is open source(python based framework).But,it is command line utility.We have to execute DOS command from C# code.So, it sounds like unmanageable.Thats why we avoided.. Anyways thanks for reply..

Answer (score 0):

Check out the open source [.NET X12parser](http://x12parser.codeplex.com/). It's already got fairly robust support for the X12 healthcare formats (including 837). You'll just supply the 837 data in a XML format and it will create a valid X12 file.

Comment: This looks to be the opposite of what the OP is asking.  This seems to be EDI 837 to XML conversion package, not vise-versa that is needed.